# How to call a function, passing the return value (possibly void) of a functor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given a function that calls a templated function argument and calls another function that does something with the returned value:

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) {
    // ...
}

template <typename T_Func>
void call(T_Func &&func) {
    doSomething(func());
}
```

How can this be extended to work with a functor that returns `void`? Ideally, I would like to add an overloaded `void doSomething() { ... }` that is called if `func`'s return type is `void`.

Currently this just results in an `error: invalid use of void expression` if `func` returns `void`.

[Working example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/anl0Y2)

Comment: You could use a combination of `std::enable_if` and `decltype` to create two overloads of `call()` that handle the `void` and non-`void` return type cases differently.

Comment: @JasonR True, but I already have 4 variations of `call` in the actual code, and would like to avoid doubling that to 8.

Comment: @zennehoy *cough* [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) *cough*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could create a struct helper to use overloaded `,` operator more or less like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct my_void { };
struct my_type { };

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
my_void operator,(T, my_type) { return {}; }

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T &&operator,(T &&val, my_type) { return std::forward<T>(val); }

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) {
}

template <typename T_Func>
void call(T_Func &&func) {
    doSomething((func(), my_type{}));
}

int main() {
    auto func1 = []() -> bool { return true; };
    auto func2 = []() -> void { };
    call(func1);
    call(func2);
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9clPilfe4WmcEBQH)

**Edit:**

Thanks to Piotr Skotnicki and Holt (they pointed out that the first overload actually wouldn't ever be triggered and proposed simplified version of the approach):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct dumb_t { };

template <class T>
T &&operator,(T &&val, dumb_t) { return std::forward<T>(val); }

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) {
}

template <typename T_Func>
void call(T_Func &&func) {
    doSomething((func(), dumb_t{}));
}

int main() {
    auto func1 = []() -> bool { return true; };
    auto func2 = []() -> void { };
    call(func1);
    call(func2);
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eTC4ySN3RhyEilf9)

Comment: How does the first `operator,` works? If `T` is `void`, this is basically `operator,(void, my_type)` which should not compile... Is there a special rule for templated-function arguments allowing `void` here?

Comment: I don't think `my_void operator,(T, my_type)` works the way you think it does

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki how so? shouldn't it match to `(void(), my_type{})`?

Comment: @W.F. I don't think you can overload `operator,` with `void` - The first overload is never called in your code, which mean that `(func(), my_type{})` simply returns `my_type{}`.

Comment: my, my... so the second overload is take care of everything here?

Comment: @W.F. Nonetheless, the idea works I think, you simply need only one custom type with an overload `operator,`, since the overload will never be chosen for `void`.

Comment: @Holt really did not expect that :)

Comment: @W.F. Finally, you just need to overload `doSomething` for `dumb_t` or `my_void` and fall backs to `doSomething()` in order to get what OP wants I think (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xTzOXyd70ycyq2Pq).

Comment: @Holt yep lets hope that the overloading of `doSomething` won't be the problem for OP (as I did not get from OPs comment overloading which function OP would like to avoid)

Comment: @W.F. Nope, overloading `doSomething` for `void` or some other void-indicating type was what I wanted to achieve. The Edited approach is exactly what I had hoped to get working.

Answer (score 1):

`doSomething()` takes a parameter, and a parameter cannot be void.

So, in order for this to work, you also need an overloaded `doSomething()` that takes no parameters. This is going to be the first step:

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) {
    // ...
}

void doSomething()
{
}
```

So, you're going to have to do this first, before you can even get off the ground.

It's also possible that you would like to supply a default value for the parameter, in case the functor returns a `void`; and still use a single template. That's another possibility, and the following solution can be easily adjusted, in an obvious way, to handle that.

What needs to happen here is a specialization of `call()` for a functor that returns a `void`. Unfortunately, functions cannot be partially specialized, so a helper class is needed:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) {
    // ...
}

void doSomething()
{
}

// Helper class, default implementation, functor returns a non-void value.

template<typename return_type>
class call_do_something {

public:

    template<typename functor>
    static void call(functor &&f)
    {
        doSomething(f());
    }
};

// Specialization for a functor that returns a void.
//
// Trivially changed to call the template function instead, with
// a default parameter.

template<>
class call_do_something<void> {

public:

    template<typename functor>
    static void call(functor &&f)
    {
        f();
        doSomething();
    }
};

// The original call() function is just a wrapper, that selects
// the default or the specialized helper class.

template <typename T_Func>
void call(T_Func &&func) {
    call_do_something<decltype(func())>::call(std::forward<T_Func>(func));
}

// Example:

void foobar()
{
    call([] { return 1; });
    call([] {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an extra pair of overloaded helper functions (named `callDispatch` in my example below) to dispatch the call as required, which eliminates the need for partial specialisation and thus helper classes. They are overloaded by using different signature specifications for the `std::function` objects they take (live code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b16216f6b3ce518a)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int func1()
{
    return 1;
}

void func2()
{
}

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T &&) 
{
    std::cout << "In param version" << std::endl;
    // ...
}

void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "In no-param version" << std::endl;
    // ...
}

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
void callDispatch(std::function<R(Args...)> &&f)
{
    doSomething(f());
}

template <typename ... Args>
void callDispatch(std::function<void(Args...)> &&f)
{
    f();
    doSomething();
}

template <typename T>
void call(T &&func) {
    callDispatch(std::function<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(func));
}

int main() {
    call(func1);
    call(func2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One lean variant would be to give the method a function as parameter. Then you evaluate the expression inside the method and see if did anything. In general this is usally bad practice, since you usually can infer how it returns stuff and when it is needed.